# No message in queue if i set additionnal properties to my message

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq, php-amqplib

I'm using `symfony 3.4` with `RMQ 3.6.14`. I was dealing with additional properties, but surpisingly, the message never reached `RMQ` server.

I put some debug point everywhere, but i can not explain it.
I'm using `php-amqlib 2.7.2`.

**if i do :**

```
$this->producer->publish(
            serialize($batch),
            $importType);
```

No problem, i can see my message ,

**but since i did :**

```
$this->producer->publish(
            serialize($batch),
            $importType,
            array('message_id' => $file->getClientOriginalName(), 'user_id' => (string)$user->getId(), 'app_id' => (string)$brand->getId()));
```

I can not see it in my queues :(
Nb: i configured an exchanger to route my message to different queue according to routing key.

Any idea ? I'm stuck with it.

Have a nice day,

Greg